# Why is sprite image flashing/filckering?

Tags: python, pygame

How can i prevent the sprite image from flickering uncontrollably? (image name is plumbers). when you run the program the only image flickering is the sprite.

```
import pygame
import os, sys
import itertools
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

cloud_background = pygame.image.load('clouds.bmp')
brick_tile = pygame.image.load('brick_tile.png')
plumbers = pygame.image.load('Mario_sideways_sprite_2xL.png')

pink = (255, 64, 64)
w = 640
h = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
running = 1

def setup_background():
    screen.fill((pink))
    screen.blit(cloud_background,(0,0))
    brick_width, brick_height = brick_tile.get_width(), brick_tile.get_height()
    for x,y in itertools.product(range(0,640,brick_width),
                                 range(390,480,brick_height)):
        # print(x,y)
        screen.blit(brick_tile, (x,y))


def show_sprites():
    screen.blit(plumbers,(50,337))
    pygame.display.flip()



while running:
    show_sprites()
    setup_background()
    pygame.display.flip()
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
```

Comment: You flip in show_sprites and after setting up the background. Try removing the flip in show_sprites, that might work (Can't test atm)

Comment: if i take away the "flip" then no image apears...

Comment: I think you want to call setup_background() and then show_sprites(), so the sprites are drawn over the background. Also remove pygame.display.flip() from show_sprites as Glider said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know pygame, but whilst you wait for answer from someone with more experience in this area.  I can offer this advice which might help.

Your setting up the background from scratch each time which is a processor intensive process. The best approach is to instead actually only re-render the part of the background required. I.e the parts where your plumber sprite occupied before.

Normally you do this by creating two variables called old X, old Y.  This the rendering process is spend up.

Currently your render the entire screen every loop cycle.